# Using heap memory for reading files

Tags: c++, file, memory

To read data from a file, I create heap memory then pass the variable pointer to a function so `fread()` will put the file data into the pointer. But when the function returns, there is no data in the new created memory.

```
int main(...) {
  MyFile File;
  File.Open(...);
  int filesize = File.Tell();
  char* buffer = new buffer[filesize]; // Create some memory for the data 
  File.Read((char**)&buffer);

  // Now do something with the buffer. BUT there is trash in it.

  File.Close();
  delete [] buffer;
}

size_t File::Read(void* buf) {
  ...

  ::fseek(fStream, 0, SEEK_END);
  int fileSize = ::ftell(fStream);  // Get file size.
  ::fseek(fStream, 0, SEEK_SET);

  ::fread(buf, 1, fileSize, fStream);

  return (fileSize);
}
```

Yes, I can put `char * myBuffer = new char[fileSize];` inside of `File::Read(...)` before `::fread(myBuffer, 1, fileSize, fStream);`,
but I should not have to do this because I already have heap memory
(`buffer`) in `main()`.

Comment: Given `size_t File::Read(void* buf);`, what do you think you're doing with `File.Read((char**)&buffer);`?!?!

Comment: Because 'buf' in Read parameter is 'void *'. i think i have to cast it to (char**)&bufer.  I try just Read( &buffer) and Read( buffer) but it still is not working

Answer (score 2):

You're reading your file contents into the pointer `buffer`, not the array it points to.

You're overcomplicating things anyway.  You don't need a pointer to a pointer, or a `void*`.  You can simply pass a `char*` to `Read`.  You should really also pass the size of the buffer pointed to into `Read` as well.  Otherwise you risk overflowing your buffer.

```
int main() {
    MyFile File;
    File.Open(/*.....*/);
    int filesize = File.Tell()
    char* buffer = new buffer[filesize]; // Create some memory for the data 
    File.Read(buffer, filesize);

    // Now do something with the buffer. BUT there is trash in it.

    File.Close();
    delete [] buffer;
}

size_t File::Read(char* buf, size_t count) {
    // ......

    // No need to find the size of the file a second time

    // Return the actual number of bytes read
    return ::fread(buf, 1, count, fStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my function to:

```cpp
size_t nvFile::Read( char * pszBuffer, const size_t uiCount ) ...
```

Thank you Miles Budnek! I did not think enought of my problem. I am opening a binary file and it is a byte (char), so it not have to be void *. (I put on my 'cone-of-shame' for not thinking.)

Thank you for help and makeing me think more. :)

Comment: You might want to delete this answer and accept Miles's.